# How to prevent aggregate function removing a column?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with 3 columns. I group by one column and want to aggregate on the max of these groups of another column. However I want to retain my 3rd column.
[This is the dataframe I start with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrEww.png). Then I group by "neighbourhood" and aggregate the max of "Amount".

```
agg_dict = {"Amount": np.max}
listings_group.groupby("neighbourhood").agg(agg_dict).reset_index()
```

But [this is the dataframe I end up with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEb2T.png). It does almost what I want, however I also want to retain my column "room_type".

**Edit**

Dataframe before groupby

```
neighbourhood   room_type   Amount
0   Allerton    Entire home/apt 7
1   Allerton    Private room    14
2   Allerton    Shared room 2
3   Arden Heights   Private room    4
4   Arrochar    Entire home/apt 12
5   Arrochar    Private room    3
6   Arverne Entire home/apt 29
7   Arverne Private room    43
8   Arverne Shared room 2
```

Dataframe after groupby

```
    neighbourhood   Amount
0   Allerton    14
1   Arden Heights   4
2   Arrochar    12
3   Arverne 43
4   Astoria 458
5   Bath Beach  7
6   Battery Park City   45
7   Bay Ridge   55
```

Comment: Please add the dataframes (or data samples of your problem) in a way that can be copied into a text editor.

Comment: Since you want the other column, I assume you would also want all the rows, as opposed to an aggregated number of rows. One way is to join the newly created dataframe to the existing one.

Comment: Made the edit. Is this the right way?

Comment: @Rohith merging is not an option in this case. I'm not really interested in "amount". This is merely the amount room_type x,y and z occur in a certain neighbourhoud. But I want to have the room_type that is most used per neighbourhood.

Comment: as your requirement, I think you need this:  `listings_group.loc[listings_group.groupby("neighbourhood")['Amount'].idxmax()]`

Comment: @AndyL. this did the trick. However right now I don't really know what I'm doing. How does this differ from my solution?

Comment: @Babhoster: I added the answer to give detail explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try slicing with groupby `idxmax` on `Amount`

```
listings_group.loc[listings_group.groupby("neighbourhood")['Amount'].idxmax()]

Out[347]:
   neighbourhood        room_type  Amount
1  Allerton       Private room     14
3  Arden Heights  Private room     4
4  Arrochar       Entire home/apt  12
7  Arverne        Private room     43
```

---

**Step by step**:

groupby `idxmax` on column `Amount` will return index of row where value of `Amount` in each group is max.

```
m = listings_group.groupby("neighbourhood")['Amount'].idxmax()

Out[348]:
neighbourhood
Allerton         1
Arden Heights    3
Arrochar         4
Arverne          7
Name: Amount, dtype: int64
```

`.loc` with `m` will slice and return only rows where index values are equal to values in `m`

```
listings_group.loc[m]

Out[352]:
   neighbourhood        room_type  Amount
1  Allerton       Private room     14
3  Arden Heights  Private room     4
4  Arrochar       Entire home/apt  12
7  Arverne        Private room     43
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `scipy.stats`

```
listings_group.groupby('neighbourhood')['room_type'].agg(lambda x:scipy.stats.mode(x)[0]).reset_index()
```